# How would I get SMS/Phone events, and act on them before they're sent to the system apps?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sms, jailbreak

I'm trying to develop an application for a jailbroken iPhone similar to Mcleaner or iBlacklist.

What I want my app to be able to do is intercept SMS or Phone events and handle them before they're sent to the appropriate receiver. So for example, I want the application to get an SMS event, compare the sender to an array of numbers, and either process the data or ignore it and pass it off to the SMS app.

In MCleaner, you can define a blacklist of numbers, and if a text message is received that matches the blacklist the user won't get an alert from the phone and the data is instead handled by MCleaner.

How would I go about getting these events, and further, how would I get these before the appropriate apps receive them? From what I understand, I'd need to become a first responder for these things, but I really have no clue where to start. I can't seem to find any hints on how I'd go about this as this app will not be calling apple classes to get the data..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guide in with this, sorry, the code isn't mine to give.

In memory, all the action calls are all just pointers. What you have to do is over ride the pointer to make it point to your own function. Once you do that, you do w/e you want in your function, and then call the default function call. This ensures the integrity of the action calls and allows you to intercept the actions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've been hooking with mobilesubstrate for the last while as I gather it's the only way to do this, however I can't for the life of me find the classes to override. I'm going through tonnes of dumped private classes to no avail.

Any hints as to the methods and classes to hook?

Comment: You're on the right path :P. I don't know the specific methods/classes though :(.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the CKMessage class.

Check this out:  http://hexorcist.com/private_frameworks/html/interface_c_k_message.html

and this:  http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=232745